# Why does SQL*Plus commit on exit?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Surely this should be the same as a termination of a session and cause a rollback? It seems to me to be the most un-Oracle thing possible. I was actually shocked when I found out that it did this

More importantly - would anyone object if Oracle changed it to rollback on exit?

Comment: Regarding change - there are bound to be thousands of scripts that would break if the default behaviour were changed.  If it was a configurable option (somehow), maybe it would be OK to change the default, but not otherwise.  That's life with software that has been fielded for more than about 1 minute - you can't change decisions easily.

Comment: I think it's easily changed. I've encountered problems with SQL*Plus not autocommitting and that really confusing people, or perhaps it was that it didn't commit yet since the app was still open.

Comment: It is available as an option on the new 11gR2 SQL*Plus

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Funnily enough, with the 11gR2 release this week (2009-09-03), SQL*Plus now has an option to COMMIT or ROLLBACK on EXIT. Doc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG079)

I'd guess in the next few weeks/months, there'll be an 11gR2 Instant Client which you can use against your current database and get your desired behaviour

A caution to be aware of. If you [DISCONNECT or CONNECT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve015.htm#sthref1442) to a different session, it will still implicitly commit the transaction (according to the doc).

Comment: I would like to see that link if you please :)

Comment: link discontinued

Answer (score 6):

It was a design decision by Oracle, probably made more than 20 years ago.  It is not the design I would have used.  Note that it seems to be a property of SQL*Plus, not of the underlying OCI.

If the session terminates abruptly, AFAIK, the session is rolled back, as you'd expect.  So, for example, if someone sends a SIGKILL to SQL*Plus, the session's transaction should be rolled back.  But if the SQL*Plus session terminates gracefully (EOF or exit command), then SQL*Plus in its infinite wisdom decides to commit whatever you've done so far.

As to why - I have a theory.  In SQL standard databases, you are always in a transaction, even if the only operation you've performed is a SELECT statement.  If you don't commit, then any changes you make are rolled back.  It is easy to forget to add commit to the end of scripted operations, so making it the default behaviour reduced the number of times someone ran a script to change the database and then ran a second script to see whether the changes took effect correctly.  Other DBMS obviate the need for this with modes like 'auto-commit', where each statement is a standalone transaction, automatically committed on completion.  That's a useful mode of operation.  Other systems provide a mode where you are in auto-commit until you run an explicit BEGIN WORK statement, whereupon (of course), you are in a transaction until the corresponding COMMIT or ROLLBACK.  I have been caught out by 'MODE ANSI' databases not committing sufficiently often to make sure that I commit when it matters, but the software I use (not Oracle) still rolls back uncommitted work rather than silently committing it for you - and I would be unhappy if it was changed to work otherwise.  (I suppose a configurable default might be OK; I still think rollback uncommitted is the better default, for all it is a nuisance to the unaware; there is less danger of accidentally corrupting a database, and that is of paramount importance to me.)

(*Due notice:* This is second-hand information from someone who works for another DBMS vendor.  It is, however, accurate as far as I know, and based on information accumulated over a period of more than a decade and after asking related questions in various forums.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment Jonathan - I'm waiting to see if anyone thinks the commit is actually a good idea!

Answer (score 3):

You'd have to ask Oracle!

I must admit that I was surprised when I first discovered this, since you'd think it would take the more conservative approach which would be to do a ROLLBACK.

I can only guess that COMMIT is considered to be the most likely / default action and maybe this is why SQL*Plus does it?

Comment: But surely ROLLBACK is the safest thing. *Everything* else in Oracle seems to be set up to protect the data

Comment: I agree,  It think the SQL*Plus behaviour is odd too!

Answer (score 1):

Good question.

I had a look on metalink and a bug (or change request) has been raised against the default behaviour of committing on normal exit back in 1998. If you have access to metalink look for bug 633247.

Comment: Actually last week :) It's in the new 11gr2 release

Answer (score 1):

Consistent with how a jdbc connection using an Oracle driver implicitly commits the txn on closing the connection.

Comment: I couldn't seem to find where this is documented. Not that I doubt you but are you able to cite your source?

Comment: ojdbc14.jar when OracleManagedConnection cleanup is called it checks to see if a valid transaction is currently in progress. In the situation a transaction is in progress is throws a IllegalStateException.

Answer (score 0):

I think the commit is a good idea and I agree with what Justin and Billy wrote in this thread: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=3611345&#3611345

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: I don't disagree with Justin and Billy in the thread - however that doesn't make the commit a good idea. Commit on exit seems to suggest that it is expected behaviour not to explicitly commit your work before exiting SQL*Plus, as if that were a good thing.

Comment: Each script should handle transactions explicitly, without relying on some clients default behaviour. That's why I think this behaviour is really not so important. And for the cases a transaction is left open, the application has to choose between commit, rollback, or ask. Choosing to commit seems a logical choice to me, although the other two would be fine as well. Most of the time you don't issue DML to have it rollbacked, that's why I think commit is a good idea. But as already said: don't make your scripts depend on that in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Committing at exit seems the logical thing to me, generally `ROLLBACK` is the exception, we rollback when something goes wrong, when you insert, update or delete data then you mean to do this i.e. `COMMIT`.