# What happens to uncommitted sql statements?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, transactions

I'm doing a statement that requires me to execute a package, do the sql and then commit.

The execution of the sql is what determines if it is successfull or not, and I'm checking the number for affected row of the sql code. If its anything but 1 the commit (a seperate command) is never runs.

What happens to the two other commands, as I said I do a command where i execute a package, the sql itself in two commands?

Comment: Are you connecting with ODBC?  If yes, are you using the default settings or explicit transaction management?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` statements, then the work will be rolled back when the session ends.

Some detailed explanation you'll find in [Transation Management Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96524/c17trans.htm)

**UPDATE** APC is right, the doc is more specific than me:

> A transaction ends when any of the following occurs:
>
> A user issues a COMMIT or ROLLBACK statement without a SAVEPOINT
>   clause.
>
> A user runs a DDL statement such as CREATE, DROP, RENAME, or ALTER. If
>   the current transaction contains any DML statements, Oracle Database
>   first commits the transaction, and then runs and commits the DDL
>   statement as a new, single statement transaction.
>
> A user disconnects from Oracle Database. The current transaction is
>   committed.
>
> A user process terminates abnormally. The current transaction is
>   rolled back.
>
> **Note:** Applications should always explicitly commit or undo transactions before program termination.

So, I didn't really answered to your question. It depends on what your connector does at disconection.

Comment: It depends also how tool handes it. Oracle SQL developer asks when you want to quit - do you want to commit or rollback. 
sqlplus is known to COMMIT on exit. Maybe SQL developer does the same when simulating script mode...

Comment: Yes, the tool may change the behavior at a **normal** exit. See a discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368092/why-does-sqlplus-commit-on-exit). But I thought he makes the tool because the question is tagged with C# :)

Comment: Sorry but this answer is too simplistic.  Even the doc you link to Oracle says that Oracle will commit the transaction if the user disconnects unless it is an abnormal termination when it will rollback.

Comment: Yes, it is simplistic. I believed that sqlplus is an exception. It is interesting that they state: _Applications should always explicitly commit or roll back transactions before program termination_ . Maybe they don't quarantee that behavior or just is not a good practice to rely on this behaviour?

Comment: @APC I would like to see a better answer for this question. Can you take some minutes to write an answer?