# CTRL+c is not working in oracle 11g to stop execution of script in sqlplus

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I was using oracle database 10g , on executing any script (say abc.sql) with sqlplus , I used to press CTRL+C to stop execution and get back to sql> . So after analysis , I can write Rollback or commit. But after  upgrading to oracle 11g CTRL+c terminates the sql execution as well as exit from sqlplus , which leads to committing the code.

I tried googling a lot , not getting any satisfactory answer . Also oracle documentation pointing that ctrl+c will only terminate the sql execution.

Can any one else faces the same issue , or guide me how to achieve the sql execution termination , So user can rollback or commit after completion of script in oracle 11g.

Thanks in advanced

Comment: What OS are you using? What shell? Are these identical for your 10g and 11g client?

Comment: possible duplicate?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368092/why-does-sqlplus-commit-on-exit

Comment: Frank I am using window OS and , on 10g it were working fine

Comment: @Ditto , I was looking for stopping sql execution , so that user can commit and rollback explicitly . Like ctrl+c was in oracle 10g