# How to avoid SQL*Plus committing on exit

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have this code below:

```
INSERT INTO departments (dep_id, description)
VALUES (1, 'New Department');

EXIT;
```

I noticed every time I type exit, it will commit the insert. I already `set autocommit off` but still saves the insert. I need to manually commit the insert.

Any advice?

Comment: Perhaps would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368092/why-does-sqlplus-commit-on-exit) be useful?

Comment: When you say *I need to manually commit the insert*, did you mean *roll back*? SQL\*Plus already commits by default on exit.

Answer (score 3):

You need [`exitcommit`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#BABEGEGC) (added in SQL*Plus 11.2).

`autocommit` only applies to individual statements, and does not affect exit behaviour.