# Using DML query without commit statement

Tags: sql, oracle, commit, sqlplus, dml

What happens If we exit out of a session without committing an update statement in sqlplus. Can we commit it after logging into the session again?

Comment: No, not possible depends on your lost individual session.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368092/why-does-sqlplus-commit-on-exit) has all the details you need.

Answer (score 1):

Exit automatically issues a commit statement before leaving the sqlplus.

Comment: Additionally, exit behavior can be configured with `SET EXITC[OMMIT] {ON | OFF}` if you're running 11g or higher. [Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG079)